# Cache a lot of callback, then call them all batch-ly without v-table cost

Tags: c++, c++14, vtable

`C1`, `C2`,`...` are callback classes.
They derived from a common interface `CBase` with the callback `CBase::f()`.
All of them override `CBase::f()` with `final` modifier.

I have to register ~50 instance of ***any class that derived from*** `C1`, and ~50 instance of ***any class that derived from*** `C2`.
(see `@@` in the below code for example)

**Main objective:** When I call `allF()`,  `C1::f()` / `C2::f()` of every registered instances have to be called.

Here is a simplified version, it works ([Full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12fe884539b986ad)) :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class CBase{
    public: virtual void f(){std::cout<<"CBase"<<std::endl;}
};
class C1 : public CBase{
    public: virtual void f() final{std::cout<<"C1"<<std::endl;}
};
class C2 : public CBase{
    public: virtual void f() final{std::cout<<"C2"<<std::endl;}
};
```

This is the callback registering :-

```
//-------- begin registering -----
std::vector<CBase*> cBase;   
void regis(CBase* c){
    cBase.push_back(c);
}
void allF(){ //must be super fast
    for(auto ele:cBase){
        ele->f();    //#
    }
}
int main() {
    C1 a;
    C1 b;
    C2 c;   //@@
    //or ... class C2Extend : public C2{};   C2Extend c;  
    regis(&a);
    regis(&b);
    regis(&c);
    allF();  //print C1 C1 C2
}
```

### Problem

According to the profile result, if I can avoid the v-table cost at `#`, I would get significant performance gain.

How to do it elegantly?

### My poor solution

A possible workaround is : create many arrays to store each `CX` ([Full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e478ba0d234937f6)):-

```
//-------- begin registering -----
std::vector<C1*> c1s;
std::vector<C2*> c2s;

void regis(C1* c){
    c1s.push_back(c);
}
void regis(C2* c){
    c2s.push_back(c);
}
void allF(){ //must be super fast
    for(auto ele:c1s){
        ele->f();    //#
    }
    for(auto ele:c2s){
        ele->f();    //#
    }
}
int main() {
    C1 a;
    C1 b;
    C2 c;
    regis(&a);
    regis(&b);
    regis(&c);
    allF();  //print C1 C1 C2
}
```

It is very faster.
However, it is not scale well.
After a few development cycle, `C3`,`C4`, etc were born.
I have to create `std::vector<C3*>`,`std::vector<C4*>`, ... manually
My approach lead to maintainability hell.

**More information (edited)**

In the worst case, there are at most 20 classes. (`C1` to `C20`)

In real case, `C1`,`C2`,... are special type of data-structures.
All of them require special initialization (`f()`) at a precisely-correct time.

Their instances are constructed at various `.cpp`.
Thus, an array storage `std::vector<CBase*> cBase;` caching all of them would be useful.

For example, `C1` is `map 1:1`, `C2` is `map 1:N`, `C3` is `map N:N`.
Together with a custom allocator, I can achieve unearthly data locality.

**More note:** I don't care about order of callback.   (Thank *Fire Lancer*)

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by all those classes? Can't you use lambdas or non-virtual classes and store everything as [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? Having around 50 callback-classes like you smells like a design problem, perhaps you should take a few steps back to get a broader view of the problem, its current solution and desing, and maybe even reiterate the design?

Comment: @Some programmer dude  It is the core part inside a game engine.  It is very performance critical.    So far, I have this kind of problem only 1 location among 20K lines of code.   Sadly, I can't use std::function because it is too slow.  ..... In real case, `C1`,`C2`,... are like "map1to1", "map1toN","mapNtoN", ...

Comment: He wants to optimise out a virtual call. A `std::function` is not going to solve that, your just making a different type of indirect call. In fact, wouldnt be surprised if `std::function` is **slower**.

Comment: Have you tried sorting cBase by type? I think this is one trick for polymorphic collections - you don't eliminate the vtable overhead, but you ensure it's all in cache, branch/jump prediction is correct, etc. That assumes you have many instances of each type

Comment: @Stefan Atev  I agree that I should try.    Fire Lancer also mentioned about it in his answer.  Thank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "poor solution" starts looking much better when you automate it using templates. Our goal: store `c1s`, `c2s`, etc in a single vector.

To do this, we need to map derived types to consecutive integers. A simple way to do that is to use a global counter, and a function template that increments and stores it every time it is instantiated.

```
static std::size_t typeIndexCounter = 0;

template <class>
std::size_t indexForType() {
    static std::size_t const index = typeIndexCounter++;
    return index;
}
```

The first call to `indexForType<T>()` will reserve a new index for `T`, and return the same one on subsequent calls.

Then, we need a way to erase enough information about our callback vectors so we can store them and call the correct `f` on them.

```
struct Group {
    using CbVec = std::vector<void *>;

    void (*call)(CbVec &);
    CbVec callbacks;
};

static std::vector<Group> groups;
```

`call` will hold a function that iterates over the pointers, downcasts them and calls `f`. Just like your solution, this factors out all of the calls to a single type into only one virtual call.

`CbVec` could hold `CBase *` instead of `void *`, but I'll explain that choice later.

Now we need a function to populate `groups` upon requesting a `Group`for some type:

```
template <class T>
Group &groupFor() {

    std::size_t const index = indexForType<T>();
    if(index < groups.size())
        // Group already exists, return it
        return groups[index];

    assert(
        index == groups.size() &&
        "Something went wrong... Did someone call detail_callbacks::indexForType?"
    );

    // Register the new group, with its downcasting function
    groups.push_back({
        [](Group::CbVec &callbacks) {
            for(void *p : callbacks)
                static_cast<T*>(p)->f();
        },
        {}
    });

    // Return the new group
    return groups.back();
}
```

Here you can see that we use a lambda expression to generate the downcasting functions. The reason I've chosen to store `void *`'s instead of `CBase *`'s is that the performance-sensitive downcast in there becomes a no-op, while a base-to-derived cast might have required pointer adjustments (and further complications in case of virtual inheritance).

Finally, the public API. All of the above has been defined inside `namespace detail_callbacks`, and we just need to put the pieces together:

```
template <
    class T,
    class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<CBase, T>::value>
>
void regis(T *callback) {
    detail_callbacks::groupFor<T>().callbacks.push_back(static_cast<void*>(callback));
}

void allF() {
    for(auto &group : detail_callbacks::groups)
        group.call(group.callbacks);
}
```

And there you go! New derived callbacks are now automatically registered.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3d6ba4cbee71f40)

Comment: I will take time to understand, but it looks like what I want.  It is not uglier than I expect.  Thank.

Answer (score 3):

You could pull the globals into a class templated over the derived type, and when that is instantiated, ensure that it is part of the overall call.

```
typedef void(*Action)(); // function pointer type, receives static call 
std::set<Action> allFs; 

template<typename T>
struct FRegistry 
{
    static std::vector<T*> ts;
    static void doF() 
    { 
        // loop over the derived type, so no need for virtual
        for (T * t : ts) { t->f(); } 
    }
    static void regis(T * item) 
    { 
        allFs.insert(&FRegistry::doF); // Ensure the global call includes this instantiation
        ts.push_back(t); // register the instance
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T*> FRegistry<T>::ts = {}; // member initialisation

template <typename T>
regis(T * t)
{ 
    FRegistry<T>::regis(t); 
}

void allF()
{ 
    for (Action a : allFs) { a(); } // call each doF
}
```

Usage is unchanged

```
int main() {
    C1 a;
    C1 b;
    C2 c;
    regis(&a);
    regis(&b);
    regis(&c);
    allF();  //print C1 C1 C2
}
```

Comment: I've added a helper function template to make the usage identical to what you already have

Comment: @cppBeginner I forgot to initialise the static data, fixed

Comment: It contains a few minor syntax errors.  But after a little fix, it works.  Thank.  (runable demo - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d41e1bd906d2984d)

Comment: note that you can drop the base class, and virtual from the `f`s

Answer (score 1):

A virtual call is already a very simple and fast implementation, so if thats a problem, nothing will be fast enough without a structural change. Notably I wouldnt expect a simple `std::function` or manually working with function pointers to be a great gain. Essentially a virtual call might look like:

```
class CBase{
    // Compiler generated
    struct Vtable
    {
        void (CBase::*f)();
    };
    public: virtual void f(){std::cout<<"CBase"<<std::endl;}

    // Compiler addded instance field
    Vtable *vtable;
};
class C1 : public CBase{
    public: virtual void f() final{std::cout<<"C1"<<std::endl;}
    // Compiler generated static data to initialise vtable member
    static Vtable C1::type_vtable = { &C1::f };
};


CBase *ptr = vector.front();
ptr->f();
// Gets compiled as
ptr->(*ptr->vtable->f)();
```

So at the code level, its a couple of extra memory reads and then calling a function via a function pointer. However, this prevents many optimisations. At the compiler level, it can no longer inline the function. At the CPU level you need `ptr->vtable` to be in the CPU cache and risk it failing branch prediction, both of which have far higher costs compared to a direct function call than than a few memory reads might imply. This is especially the case if you have many base classes and they are ordered fairly randomly in the container (the CPU is likely to keep guessing wrong which is next).

The most optimial solution without a design change is more like you showed. Get rid of the virtual/indirect functions entirely and store in separate containers. This lets the compiler inline the function call if it thinks its worth it, and makes it easy for the CPU. You could maybe use overloads or templates, so only have at worst one place to call (and with templates, depending on needs something even more clever).

```
class Register
{
    std::vector<C1*> c1;
    std::vector<C2*> c2;


    void regis(C1 *c1);
    void regis(C2 *c2);
    //etc.
};
```

Be aware that you changed the order the objects are invoked. You sorted them by class type, but before was in the same order as `regis` was called.

Just sorting by class type (could use `typeid` or such)  would also likely help the CPU somewhat, but you still loose inlining.

"Profile Guided Optimisation" (PGO, look it up in the compiler, MSVC and GCC for example can do this) might also help, with some extra build time effort. It lets the compiler optimise based on the code is that is actually run. Ive not looked in detail, at the generated code for real projects, but I understand MSVC at least can "inline" common virtual calls using like a switch statement on the `typeid`, allowing for better optimisations and possibly working nicer with modern CPUs.

A more major design change is to avoid small virtual functions. Make the virtual functions at a higher level (e.g. pass an entire container to a virtual function, rather than each element).